# Completely replace value of variable in Node.js Unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to test a (to me) complex piece of code that I would like to just return dummy data so I can do assertions on how it is handled. Here is the code:

```
const { sql, dbConnPoolPromise } = require('../database/db.js');
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const pool = await dbConnPoolPromise
        const result = await pool.request()
            .query(SQL_SELECT_ALL);
        res.status(200);
        res.json(result.recordset[0]);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500);
        res.send("ERROR, General Get" + err.message);
    }
});
```

I want to replace the *const result* with a set piece of dummy data, thus mocking the response a SQL server might give.
I cannot figure out how to do this.
I am currently using Jest as my testing suite and was hoping to use spyOn or Jest.fn() to replace it but that only works on functions. Is there a way in jest to replace variables? I cannot replace the entire router.get as I am testing that res.status(200) (amongst others)  is being sent correctly to the client, I only want to replace the value of the variable.

If required the contents of dbConnPoolPromise are:

```
let sql = require('mssql');
const config = require('config');
let dbConnPoolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config.get('connection'))
        .connect()
        .then(pool => {
        return pool
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed - error: ', err))
module.exports = {
    sql, dbConnPoolPromise, buildSelect
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your query from a service wrapper, something like.

```js
export function async getAllItems() {
  const pool = await dbConnPoolPromise
  return await pool.request().query(SQL_SELECT_ALL)
}
```

Then you can use jest's manual mocks functionality https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks to mock out the response of getAllItems.

As a broader comment, this is usually why we have patterns to access DB from a repository or service rather than directly hitting it from a controller or route like this. Once you wrap it in a service, it makes it so much easier for you to mock it out during a test.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In hindsight I probably should have made a service wrapper for all my requests to the DB but this was my first time making a server side app that makes requests to databases. If I went down this method I would have to rewrite all my requests (router.get, router.post etc.) yes? I cannot simply intercept the variable?

Comment: There is no way that I know of that you can change the value of that variable with the code you have, because what you need to change is not the variable but the value returned, which in turn gets stored in that variable and to do that you need to mock the right hand side of the `=` sign.

Yes there is one really ugly way... you could manual mock `dbConnPoolPromise` to return `pool` which has a func `request()` which returns another func `query()` and you mock the return of this.

Ugly, but works :)